# Failing to build libgit2

Tags: cmake, libgit2

I am trying to build the libgit2 library on Windows 11 x64, but having some issues.

I run

```
cmake .. -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
```

But got the errors:

```
CMake Error at deps/http-parser/CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: http-parser    
CMake Error at deps/xdiff/CMakeLists.txt:5 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: xdiff
CMake Error at deps/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: zlib
CMake Error at src/libgit2/CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: libgit2
CMake Error at src/util/CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: util
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please add more detail about your operating system, commands you execute, and errors and warnings that you see.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, im new here and couldn't find the edit option

Comment: please also include how you obtained the sources (git clone ???), where you run the commands, and what the file-structure looks like, because your errors look like files are missing.

Comment: The script [deps/http-parser/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/main/deps/http-parser/CMakeLists.txt) collects sources using `file(GLOB)` command, and there is file [deps/http-parser/http_parser.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/main/deps/http-parser/http_parser.c) which matches for the globbing expression (`*.c`). Check that content of the script `deps/http-parser/CMakeLists.txt` on your machine corresponds to the referenced one, and that your have `deps/http-parser/http_parser.c` file.

Comment: @julaine i downloaded the latest release SC.

I ran the commands exactly as the instructions say mkdir build -> cd build ->cmake ..

Comment: @Tsyvarev both are present and seem to be fine :(